# URLSession returns HTTP 403 error page

Tags: swift, post, httprequest, nsurlsession, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to run a HTTP Request in Swift, to POST 2 parameters to a URL. 
But it always returns 403 error page, what's wrong?

I trying adding Content-type header, but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
    print("ENVIAR DATOS")

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.portaljuridico.com.co/portaljuridico/User/login")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let param = ["username" : "juan", "password" : "123"]
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: []) else { return }

    //request.addValue("application/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    //request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    //request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error = \(error!)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response!)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString!)")
    }

    task.resume()
```

Comment: Use postString as dictionary not string. Also use try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options: .prettyPrinted)

Comment: I just updated it and still doesn´t work :(

Comment: Servers accepts POST data in their own ways. What sort of data your server accepts? Does it really accept JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint appears to be `http://www.portaljuridico.com.co/portaljuridico/User/loginUser` and redirects to `http://www.portaljuridico.com.co/portaljuridico/Login` on invalid user/password.